# Lower bound $L_1$ error

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a joint distribution over $X, Y$ and $h:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{Y}$ be a function mapping. Assume that there exists a universal constant $M > 0$ such that $\|h\|_\infty \leq M$ and $|Y|\leq M$. I am interested in lower bounding the $\ell_1$ error $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}[|h(X) - Y|]$ using some distance metric between the marginal distribution of $Y$ and the induced distribution of $h(\cdot)$ over $\mathcal{Y}$, are there any common techniques that could be used to construct such lower bound?

Comment: Yoiu can get proper double norm bars $\|$ by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: @joriki Thanks! Changed :)